# I want to add library from git hub

Tags: android

Here is dependency

```
 dependencies {
    compile project(':slideDateTimePicker')
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKVvJ.png)
Error:(29, 0) Project with path ':slideDateTimePicker' could not be found in project ':app'.
Open File

Comment: download library and keep inside libs folder and then add it as File dependency.

Comment: how ? may you explain just a little

Comment: Have you downloaded jar which you want to add  to your project?

Comment: No,there is full source files

Comment: what can i download ???

Comment: Here is link   https://github.com/jjobes/SlideDateTimePicker

Comment: [go through this link](https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio)

Comment: Godather it works thank you brother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under File>Project Structure>dependency you can add either file or module dependency and it will add it to your gradle.
[go through this link](https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio)

Basically it depends on where is your dependency resides if it is in local you can go by above methods else(`maven/jcenter`) you can specify direct dependencies in gradle.